# Swift PDFKit Annotation Widgets

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I may be missing something here but I can't find any documentation / sample code of how to work with PDFKit Widgets.

I've downloaded the 'PDFAnnotationWidgetsAdvanced' project' which very nicely shows how to add widgets to a PDF. Fine. But I can't find information on how to 'read' what the widget state is, update a text field etc.

For example:
- I have a PDF with several checkboxes.
- When a user clicks on a checkbox it runs a script to calculate how many of the checkboxes have been selected
- The script to detect the selection works, but I can not work out how to iterate through the checkboxes on the page and find out if they have been selected.

Note: Radiobuttons can be determined through .isHighlighted, but nothing for checkboxes.

-Then at the end of script, once it has calculated how many checkboxes have been sleected, I want the number to be presented in a textbox.
I can add textbox at the start and give it a value, but can't seem to find a way of changing it.

I find the apple documentation very poor on this topic with no tutorial / sample code on anything more than simply adding widgets not actually working with them

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: Do you just want to render the PDF or Do some advanced stuff with that?

Comment: Basically just read the values from a PDF form. I'm creating several 'outcome' forms that the user selects what applies and a total is given. Nothing too fancy